# How to avoid "make" redoing a library

Tags: libraries, make

I have a project for school.
In the root dir, I have 3 subdirs which all have a makefile (because there will be 3 executable files), and there is 1 lib dir.
This dir contains my library source files (`*.c`, `*.h`).

I have a makefile in the libdir:

```
##                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
## Makefile for corewar in /home/rihan_a/Projets/psu/corewar/lib                                                                                                                                                    
##                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
## Made by adnan rihan                                                                                                                                                                                              
## Login   <rihan_a@epitech.net>                                                                                                                                                                                    
##                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
## Started on  Fri Dec  9 09:28:07 2011 adnan rihan                                                                                                                                                                 
## Last update Fri Dec  9 10:45:27 2011 adnan rihan                                                                                                                                                                 
##                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

NAME=           libwar

SRC=            explode.c               \
                get.c                   \
                has_char.c              \
                int_to_bigendian.c      \
                my_die.c                \
                my_getnbr_t.c           \
                my_memset.c             \
                my_power_rec.c          \
                my_putstr.c             \
                my_strcat.c             \
                my_strcmp.c             \
                my_strlen.c             \
                my_strncpy.c            \
                my_strndup.c            \
                op.c                    \
                wt_len.c                \
                xmalloc.c

OBJ=            $(SRC:.c=.o)

ARFLAGS=        rcs
CFLAGS=         -Wall

all:            pack

obj_dbg:
                $(CC) -g -c $(SRC)

debug:          obj_dbg all

pack:           $(OBJ)
                $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(NAME).a $(OBJ)

clean:
                $(RM) $(OBJ)

fclean:         clean
                $(RM) $(NAME).a
```

My problem is when I do `make`, everything is ok, and for `make debug` also.
But when I do `make debug` a second time, it doesn't remake the `.o`, but does the `ar rcs` everytime.
I want to avoid it, because when I request `make -C ../lib` for the other makefiles, they all relink because the lib changed (because `ar` was run each time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no check on the library.  One way would be to replace

```
pack:           $(OBJ)
                $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(NAME).a $(OBJ)
```

by

```
pack: $(NAME).a

$(NAME).a: $(OBJ)
        $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $(NAME.a) $(OBJ)
```

so the library would not be remade if it is up to date.

Comment: Ah great thanks.
So, I HAVE to create a rule with a filename ? Then the filename will be check for changes ...?
I didn't know :/

Comment: @Max13, The principle of `make` is that it rebuilds files which are not uptodate with respects to their dependencies. I.E. all rules are file names. (Some make variant have a way to indicates that a rule hasn't the purpose to build a file, see `.PHONY` in GNUmake for instance, but then they are always executed)

Answer (score 0):

```
debug:          obj_dbg all
```

Do you need all again there? or just all?

Comment: I don't need all "again", I just need all. "make debug" will make "all", which is "$(NAME)"

Comment: you right0 there.